# Multiple integrals problem

Tags: calculus, integration

> Show that!
>   $$\int\limits_0^1
> \int\limits_0^1
> \int\limits_0^1
> \int\limits_0^1
> \int\limits_0^1
> \int\limits_0^1
> \frac{\,\mathrm du
> \,\mathrm dv
> \,\mathrm dw
> \,\mathrm dx
> \,\mathrm dy
> \,\mathrm dz}{1-uvwxyz}=\frac{\pi^6}{945}$$

I have no idea about this problem. How to solve this multiple integrals? I have strucked on this problem, please anyone solve it for me.

Comment: Where exactly did you get stuck in the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Notice that you can write
$$\frac{1}{1-uvwxyz}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (uvwxyz)^k$$
since $0<u,v,w,x,y,z<1$.

So the integral is:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1(uvwxyz)^k\,du\,dv\,dw\,dx\,dy\,dz=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k+1)^6}=\zeta(6)$$

$$=\boxed{\dfrac{\pi^6}{945}}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v\mathrm{d}w\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z}{1-uvwxyz}\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{0}{\left(uvwxyz\right)}}{uvwxyz}\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v\mathrm{d}w\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{1}{\left(vwxyz\right)}}{vwxyz}\mathrm{d}v\mathrm{d}w\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{2}{\left(wxyz\right)}}{wxyz}\mathrm{d}w\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{3}{\left(xyz\right)}}{xyz}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{4}{\left(yz\right)}}{yz}\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_{5}{\left(z\right)}}{z}\mathrm{d}z\\
&=\operatorname{Li}_{6}{\left(1\right)}\\
&=\frac{\pi^6}{945}\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: What is the Li(x) function?

Comment: It is the [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).